# Best Ptarices / Notation in es6 to a condition with some ( OR )

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am searching for good practices or notation for conditions like this:

```
    if ( el.type === 'state' || el.type === 'status' || .... )  {
    // process 
    }
```

I can use like this but i need advise

```
 function isValid() {
    let arr = ['state', 'status', '...']
    if ( arr.include( el.type ) {
    // process
    return true
    }
    return false
}

 function isValid() {
return el.type === 'state' 
      || el.type === 'status' 
      || ... 
}
```

Comment: It’s hard to say because it’s all about context. How many more are there? Could the whole function be re-written? Do you need to do this? If these are all required, should there be some kind of validation before hand? How did you let it get this far before having to do this? Too many questions, too many answers. Probably not going to get very far on Stack Overflow I’m afraid. Just remember code is for reading by humans – computers don’t care. Make it easy for another human to understand.

Comment: `['state', 'status', ...].includes(el.type)`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. Except if it is really really long, but then the question is, does it really need to be that long?

Comment: you could use an array with `includes` or `indexOf` if the list to test is long, that's not totally equal in term of performance i guess, but shorter to read. This is more preference depending on the code than good practices, though, there's nothing wrong with your code as it is

Answer (score 0):

You should use a switch statement instead of a if condition something similar to :

Check out this example here on Js Bin: 
https://jsbin.com/takadoq/edit?js,console

It's just a switch statement:

```
  switch(el.type) {
    case 'state':
    case 'status':
      return true
      break;
    default:
      return false
  }
```

Learn more about the switch case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0):

```
if (['state', 'status', '...']).includes(el.type)) ...
```

is more readable way that has been already mentioned, but only in **ES2016** and higher.

A way to do this in **ES5** and **ES6** is:

```
if (['state', 'status', '...']).indexOf(el.type) >= 0) ...
```

This provides a tiny overhead over `el.type === 'state' || el.type === 'status' || ...` condition which can be considered acceptable, unless the code is performance-critical.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your code to be readable, hide such complex cases in predicate methods:

```
if (el.isStatus()){
    // process
}
```

then all that complexity is easier to manage because you do not have to put it all in one line:

```
el.isStatus = function(){
    if (this.type === 'state') return true;
    if (this.type === 'status') return true;
    ...
    return false; // default
}
```